# Java 8: No errors - Why is this for loop running forever and not showing anything?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, infinite-loop, distribution

My issue is with the following code. Eclipse IDE gives me no errors or warnings, yet when I print out a simple `System.out.println("Test" + i);`, I would get a running program up to the number 2509, or currently 2517 after rebooting Eclipse.

Essentially, I want to take an array of objects, say an array of "persons," and place them in *random* spots in another object array, say "bus stops." *Assume that I have properly made the object arrays for "busStops and "people"*

Yes, I realize that it defeats the purpose of making the "person" object as of yet, but that is something that can be included later.

Edit: Null values are simulated areas where people can't go, like a lake.

Edit2: replaced `for` with `while` loop, replaced decremented `i` with `continue` keyword.

Edit3: added more of the methods to elaborate the imperfections of my code. Then again, maybe most of it is good and I'm not understanding something important about loops.

```
private static void distributePeople() {

    boolean temp = true;
    int i = 0;

    while (temp) {
        // Select random points in array
        int a = rand.nextInt(busStops.length);
        int b = rand.nextInt(busStops[0].length);

        // At random busStop, check if available and check if not full.
        // If it is not full, place a person there.
        if (busStops[a][b] == null) {
            // if null, reset this run
            continue;
        } else {
            if (busStops[a][b].isMaxPeople() == false) {
                busStops[a][b].setNumberOfPeople(1);
                i++;
                System.out.println("Test: " + i);
            } else {
                // if true, reset this run
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (i == people.length) {
            temp = false;
        }
    }
}

private static void setMaxPeopleAtBusStop() {
    busStops[0][0].setMaxNumberOfPeople(1977 + 2);
    busStops[1][0].setMaxNumberOfPeople(2 + 1643);
    busStops[2][0].setMaxNumberOfPeople(1643 + 1201);
    busStops[3][0].setMaxNumberOfPeople(1201 + 1267);
    busStops[0][1].setMaxNumberOfPeople(366 + 0);
    busStops[2][1].setMaxNumberOfPeople(0 + 797);
    busStops[3][1].setMaxNumberOfPeople(797 + 34);
    busStops[0][2].setMaxNumberOfPeople(1740 + 0);
    busStops[2][2].setMaxNumberOfPeople(0 + 1444);
    busStops[3][2].setMaxNumberOfPeople(1444 + 1963);
    busStops[0][3].setMaxNumberOfPeople(839 + 1131);
    busStops[1][3].setMaxNumberOfPeople(1131 + 1092);
    busStops[2][3].setMaxNumberOfPeople(1092 + 912);
    busStops[3][3].setMaxNumberOfPeople(912 + 1965);
    busStops[0][4].setMaxNumberOfPeople(1552 + 1297);
    busStops[1][4].setMaxNumberOfPeople(1297 + 1345);
    busStops[2][4].setMaxNumberOfPeople(1345 + 614);
    busStops[3][4].setMaxNumberOfPeople(614 + 1108);
    busStops[0][5].setMaxNumberOfPeople(1490 + 228);
    busStops[1][5].setMaxNumberOfPeople(228 + 187);
    busStops[2][5].setMaxNumberOfPeople(187 + 906);
    busStops[3][5].setMaxNumberOfPeople(906 + 36);
    busStops[0][6].setMaxNumberOfPeople(634 + 1293);
    busStops[1][6].setMaxNumberOfPeople(1293 + 0);
    busStops[3][6].setMaxNumberOfPeople(0 + 1929);
    busStops[0][7].setMaxNumberOfPeople(759 + 388);
    busStops[1][7].setMaxNumberOfPeople(388 + 0);
    busStops[3][7].setMaxNumberOfPeople(0 + 1149);
    busStops[0][8].setMaxNumberOfPeople(1809 + 1880);
    busStops[1][8].setMaxNumberOfPeople(1880 + 1979);
    busStops[2][8].setMaxNumberOfPeople(1979 + 954);
    busStops[3][8].setMaxNumberOfPeople(954 + 1332);
    busStops[0][9].setMaxNumberOfPeople(1890 + 408);
    busStops[1][9].setMaxNumberOfPeople(408 + 1771);
    busStops[2][9].setMaxNumberOfPeople(1771 + 587);
    busStops[3][9].setMaxNumberOfPeople(557 + 1961);

}
```

From the appropriate BusStop class:

```
static int MAX_PEOPLE_HERE;

public int setNumberOfPeople(int a) {
    return numberOfPeopleHere += a;
}

protected boolean isMaxPeople() {
    if (numberOfPeopleHere >= MAX_PEOPLE_HERE) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void setMaxNumberOfPeople(int a) {
    MAX_PEOPLE_HERE = a;
}
```

*Note: I should have a max number of 13000 people, which is smaller than the room available above.*

Comment: You should never change the loop index within the loop. Re-think your program so that it does not need to do this.

Comment: What are the lengths of your arrays? i.e. `people.length`, `busStops.length` and `busStops[0].length`? And what is the value of `MAX_PEOPLE_HERE`?

Comment: `people.length` is 25% (truncated integer) to a global variable.
`busStops.length` is the number of row in array, 4 here. `busStops[0].length` is 10 here. `MAX_PEOPLE_HERE` varies based on which bus stop it is, hence if it is full, it goes back through the loop again to find another that is not full.

Comment: I'd post your complete code (including how you allocate MAX_PEOPLE_HERE and how you instantiate the persons array).  I'm pretty certain the above code works ok, but the problem is how it is interacting with the rest of your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so your problem is that you're using a static variable for MAX_PEOPLE_HERE but you're trying to use it in a non static way.  Thus ever time you call setMaxNumberOfPeople on any bus stop you set it for *all* bus stops.

This means that MAX_PEOPLE_HERE will end up being 557 + 1961 = 2518.

I'm guessing that numberOfPeopleHere is also static and thus you can only ever 2518 people to bus stops.  If you try to do more than this then you'll end up with an infinite loop as you are seeing.

Change both MAX_PEOPLE_HERE (rename this to maxPeopleHere) and numberOfPeopleHere to local instance variables and I suspect everything will start working.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it runs farther than 2518, I got it to complete the loop and start running the next part.

Answer (score 2):

Use `continue` instead of `i--` to skip current iteration. As @Hovercraft Full Of Eels stated, you've got infinite loop because of index modification within the loop

Comment: What do you mean by index modification because I'm not sure how else to do it? I thought computers were supposed to be dumb and do exactly what you tell them to do. In this case, change the index inside a loop.

Comment: @Numbers682: yes, and you're telling your loop to loop forever! That's not smart programming. Again, don't change your loop index `i` inside the loop and you can avoid shooting yourself in the foot programmatically as you're doing.

Comment: I agree that decrementing his loop counter inside the loop isn't best practise- but I'm guessing that the underlying problem here is that number_of_stops*max_person_perStop < people.length.  In this case it's actually impossible (according to the rules of his simulation) to distribute the people amongst the stops and this is causing the infinite loop.

Comment: @d80tb7 Thanks, but that's certainly not the problem. The `MAX_PEOPLE``, and I know this for sure, is way higher overall. Individually they can get filled up, but collectively add up to more.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: @IvanPronin: I added `continue` in place of the decrements and replaced the for loop with a while loop under the condition that
    `if (totalPeopleSoFar == people.length) {
    //end while loop
    }`

It didn't change anything other than run to 2518 iterations. <- Eclipse must be laughing at me by now.